# Netbeans UTF-8 encoding problem - ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jtextfield, java-17

I am looking for help with the coding problem in NetBeans 15 , jdk (the most recent) , I have several first and last names that have the letter "Ñ" . "é" I changed the encoding but still the problem remains, it is a finished project, when exporting it does all the functions but the letters come out weird, example, I enter a random name: Ricardo Nuñez Liñan, now when I give it in search I get Ricardo NuÃ±ez LiÃ±an. I want to know if you know a code that can change those letters by characters when searching, I tried another code but it does not come out, I attach a part of the code that I put in comment, if you know another similar method I will be happy to help me to solve the data, I save the data in notepad.
[Imagen del NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRcEh.png)

The code I put to replace only the letter is :

```
          String str5 = TNombres.getText();
          String str6 = str5.replaceAll("Ã±", "ñ");
          TNombres.setText(str6);

but if one has more than one special character I would like to change them all , for example : Ñahúi José , in this case also apply to the letter é and also the Ñ :(
```

Comment: The problem is, when you have a file that's encoded with a particular charset, you can't simply assert that it's actually encoded with a charset you'd prefer it to be

Comment: Replacing characters in Strings is not the way to go, since Strings are neither UTF-8 nor 8859-1.  They're UTF-16.  The point at which you need to consider encodings is when you convert to or from Strings -- i.e., when reading or writing files that are considered as sequences of bytes.  Doing an arbitrary wrong byte-to-String conversion and then attempting to fix up the String afterwards is a doomed undertaking.

Comment: @accessviolation is quite right. What *exactly* was the motivation for changing your encoding settings which were most probably originally correct for your platform and environment?

Comment: The byte sequence 0xC3 0xB1 is **Ã±** in Latin1 and in UTF-8 it means one character, namely **ñ**

Comment: What does "give it in a search" mean?  (I don't know anything about NetBeans)

Comment: “I want to know if you know a code that can change those letters by characters when searching…” Yes, read the search results with the correct character set *before* you put the values into text fields.  Edit your question and show the code which reads those search results, so we can help you use the correct character set.

Comment: IF YOU CAN, just create several classes:
    `private void specialLetterÑ(){
        String str106 = TNombres.getText();
        String str107 = str106.replaceAll("Ã", "Ñ");
        TNombres.setText(str107);
    }
    private empty specialletter() {
        String str100 = TNombres.getText();
        String str101 = str100.replaceAll("Ã±", "ñ");
        TNombres.setText(str101);}`
   `specialletter();
    specialLetterÑ();`
and so I fill it by putting the methods in the jbuttom